# Submit an add-in only for Excel Online

Tags: ms-office, office-js, office-app

I want to submit an add-in only for Excel Online (no Excel for Mac, no Excel for Windows).

Could anyone tell me if it is possible and how to configure the manifest xml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Office store requires that the add-in works for Mac, Windows and Online with optional iPad support. It is not possible to select only some of the required platform. The same code that works on one platform should also work on the other with the addition effort being in the testing area.